# Split and Switch function for ssrs 2014

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I am trying to get values of Q1, Q2 as per below expression in SSRS 2014 but i get an Error#. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Q1, Q2

```
=Split(

"Q" & 

  Switch(Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=3,1,
    Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=6,2,
    Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=9,3,
    Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=12,4
    ) 
& "," &

"Q" &

Switch(Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=3,1,
    Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=6,2,
    Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=9,3,
    Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value)<=12,4
    )

,",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=SWITCH(
Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) >= 1   and Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) <= 3 , "Q1",
Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) >= 4   and Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) <= 6 , "Q2",
Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) >= 7   and Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) <= 9 , "Q3",
Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) >= 10  and Month(Parameters!cEndDate.Value) <= 12 , "Q4"
)
```